# firebase is not defined JavaScript

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase

```
var firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: "AIzaSyA2YUs_WP_iMTDV5_PlccJjMnWyBKYLimw",
    authDomain: "handycraft-62b03.firebaseapp.com",
    projectId: "handycraft-62b03",
    storageBucket: "handycraft-62b03.appspot.com",
    messagingSenderId: "992781817791",
    appId: "1:992781817791:web:c9e965ed426809da86330a",
    measurementId: "G-LRSKGFHQR2"
  };
  // Initialize Firebase
  firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
```

I am trying to initialize Firebase authentication into my node js project but I am getting this error that says firebase is not defined.
It would be very nice if someone could help me out.

Comment: Are you including the firebase app script?

Comment: Did you import firebase ?

Comment: Thank you so much but I got the solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

firebase is not imported to your file. Add this:

```
var firebase = require("firebase");
```

**NOTE**: This will import all of the firebase modules into your project which is a relatively large library. If you only need certain modules, import them using:

```
require("firebase/auth");
require("firebase/database");
```

If you don't have the firebase module installed, install it using:

```
npm install --save firebase
```

Comment: Thank you very much sir.